# Connecting google big query to data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to connect a custom big query query to data studio

> No connection can be established

Does this have to do something with the rights in data studio and the actual big query account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to connect it like so:

[image]

Comment: That helped, thanks, my mistake was not using the back-ticks, I was using `'`